# Continuity camera not working

Tags: iphone, mac, camera

[image]I have an issue with my Mac not seeing my iPhone for the continuity camera.

1. Both devices are up to date
2. Both have Bluetooth on
3. Both connected to the same wifi
4. iPhone has the Handoff and the Continuity camera on
5. Airplay setting is set to never on my iPhone

With all the above, it is not working.

Comment: Have you worked through all the troubleshooting steps presented in [Apple's "If Continuity Camera isn't working as expected"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244) support document?

Comment: Yes, my mac simply does not detect it

Comment: Please specify the model number and operating systems of both your Mac and your iPhone.

Comment: My Mac is Apple M1 Pro 14 inch 32GB RAM running macOS Ventura 13.0.1.

Comment: My iPhone is iPhone 13 Pro with IOS 16.1.2

Comment: I tested it on my other Mac which is Macbook 13 inch 2020 intel core i5. And, it worked with my iPhone. So, I am assuming it is to do with the new M1 chip, maybe?

Comment: I faced the same issue with my iphone 13 and macbook pro 2019